# Unable to add Hotkey functionality to firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I took an existing addon which searches a given word on google.
Here is the link: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/inline-google-search/?src=api

Addon  works by selecting text, then right clicking on it, and in context menu get an option to search it on google.

Below is the main js file:

```
exports.main = function() {};
var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  width:700,
  height: 500,
  contentURL: "about:blank",
  onHide : function(){
      this.contentURL  = "about:blank"
  }
});

var contextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");
 var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
  label: "Search Google Inline",
  context: contextMenu.SelectionContext(),
  contentScript: 'self.on("click", function () {' +
                 '  var text = window.getSelection().toString();' +
                 '  self.postMessage(text);' +
                 '});',
  onMessage: function (selectionText) {
    panel.contentURL = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+selectionText;
    panel.show();
  }
});
```

I am adding functionality so that after selecting text and pressing Ctrl+Shift+d, the search is performed for the text on google.

Few extra lines added by me at the end:

```
var { Hotkey } = require("sdk/hotkeys");
var selection = require("sdk/selection");

var showHotKey = Hotkey({
    combo: "accel-shift-d",
    onPress: function() {
        panel.contentURL = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+selection.text;
        panel.show();
    }
});
```

The above snippet I found from here : [Access selected text within a Hotkey object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861049/access-selected-text-within-a-hotkey-object)

Also there was a file harness-options.json, which in which i updated sha256 sum of main.js file and added requirements sdk/hotkeys and sdk/selection in manifest section.

But the addon fails to work after installing. Even the context menu option doesn't appear anymore. So it seems like I broke the code.

What may I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of editing the addon I created it from scratch using cfx and addon-sdk and it worked.

Comment: Yeah, I just ran your code and it worked fine for me.